# Serve different files for specific user agents using nginx

Tags: nginx, http, mobile-devices, useragent, static-files

Using nginx, how do you serve different static files for different user agents? For example, if the current user is using an iPhone, they should be served `mobile_index.html`, whereas all other user agents should be served `browser_index.html`.

Found solution:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www;

  set $mobile_request '0';
  if ($http_user_agent ~ 'iPhone') {
    set $mobile_request '1';
  }

  location =/ {
    if ($mobile_request = '1') {
      rewrite ^ /mobile_index.html;
    }
    if ($mobile_request = '0') {
      rewrite ^ /browser_index.html;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why don´t redirect the mobile users to a mobile site? like m.mysite.com ???

Comment: because that's not what I want to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a new enough version of nginx (0.9.6+), you could accomplish this with a [map](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpMapModule#map):

```
map $http_user_agent $myindex {
  default /browser_index.html;
  ~iPhone /mobile_index.html;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www;

  location = / { rewrite ^ $myindex; }
}
```

If you don't need an internal redirect (which you probably don't if you're just serving static files for the indexes), you could add a 'break' flag to the rewrite and avoid the internal redirect.

EDIT: If you're using an older version, you could do something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /var/www;

  location = / {
    set $myindex /browser_index.html;
    if ($http_user_agent ~ iPhone) {
      set $myindex /mobile_index.html;
    }
    rewrite ^ $myindex;
  }
}
```

again, using the break flag if you don't need the internal redirect.